# How to return a List field as an empty list "[]" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, post, retrofit

So I have been tackling this issue for a couple of days now. I have a Data class that is used to send information back into the API. In this instance, I have this x amount of fields. In these fields, there are three List fields with different types, as such.

The Data Classes

```
data class ApiSurveySiteUpdateBody(
        @SerializedName("UserId") val userId: Int,
        @SerializedName("SStatusId") val sStatusId: Int,
        @SerializedName("SSId") val sSId: Int,
        @SerializedName("SPONum") val sPoNum: Int,
        @SerializedName("WorkPerformanceTypeId") val workPerformTypeId: Int,
        @SerializedName("SSAddressId") val sSAddressId: Int,
        @SerializedName("WorktoPerformDate") val workToBePerformedDate: String,
        @SerializedName("CableRun") val cableRun: String,
        @SerializedName("Entrance") val entranceInfo: String,
        @SerializedName("DoorLockHardware") val doorLockHardware: String,
        @SerializedName("HandicapOperator") val handicapOperator: String,
        @SerializedName("DeviceComplete") val completedPrimaryDeviceList: List<Int>,
        @SerializedName("TemplateId") val templateId: Int,
        @SerializedName("NewDeviceList") val newDeviceList: List<ApiNewDeviceList> = emptyList(),
        @SerializedName("UpdateDeviceList") val updateDeviceList: List<ApiUpdateDeviceList> = emptyList(),
        @SerializedName("RemoveDeviceList") val removedDeviceList: List<ApiRemovedDeviceList> = emptyList()
)
```

The Converter function

```
 private fun getSomeRequestBody(
            dbInfo: DbFormWithEList,
            apiSurveySiteMedias: List<ApiSSMediaInfo>
        )
                : ApiSSUpdateBody {
            val updateRequestApi = ApiSSUpdateBody(
                userId = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.userId,
                sSId = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.sSId,
                sStatusId = dbInfo.sStatusDbInfo.sSId,
                sPoNum = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.sPoNumber,
                workPerformTypeId = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.workPerformTypeId,
                sSAddressId = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.sSAddressId,
                workToBePerformedDate = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.workToBePerformedDate,
                cableRun = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.cableRun,
                entranceInfo = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.entranceInfo,
                doorLockHardware = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.doorLockHardware,
                handicapOperator = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.handicapOperator,
                completedPrimaryDeviceList = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.completedPrimaryDeviceList.toIntList(),
                templateId = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.templateId,
                newDeviceList = List(dbInfo.equipmentList.size) { i -> // “NewDeviceList”
                    val dbEquipmentInfo = dbInfo.equipmentList[i].sSEquipmentDbInfo
                    Log.d(TAG, "NewDeviceListDB $dbEquipmentInfo")
                    val secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus = dbEquipmentInfo.secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus
                    val isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase = dbEquipmentInfo.isDeviceUpdateMode
                    
                    if (sDeviceCheckedS == CHECKED_YES && !isDuplicateDUP){
                        val newDeviceListRequestBody =  ApiNewDeviceList(
                            secondaryDeviceId = dbEquipmentInfo.secondaryDeviceId,
                            deviceInstanceId = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceInstanceId.toString(),
                            mediaNameList = dbEquipmentInfo.mediaNames,
                            deviceSerialNumber = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceSerialNumber,
                            devicePartNumber = dbEquipmentInfo.devicePartNumber,
                            deviceManufacturerName = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceManufacturer,
                            deviceInstallationDate = DateUtil.dateToStringUTCSS(dbEquipmentInfo.deviceInstallationDate),
                            deviceLocation = dbEquipmentInfo.locationInfo,
                            deviceTechnicianNotes = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceTechnicianNotes
                        )
                        Log.d(TAG, "newDeviceListRequestBodyAPI $newDeviceListRequestBody")
                        newDeviceListRequestBody
                    }
                    else if (sDeviceCheckedS == CHECKED_NO){
                        apiDeviceListMapperUpdateSS.sendDeviceNotExistsInNewDeviceList(dbEquipmentInfo)
                    }
                    else {
                        apiDeviceListMapperUpdateSS.sendEmptyNewDeviceList()
                    }
                },

                updateDeviceList = (List(dbInfo.equipmentList.size) { i ->
                    val dbEquipmentInfo = dbInfo.equipmentList[i].sSEquipmentDbInfo
                    Log.d("UpdatingSiteSurvey", "UpdateDeviceListDB $dbEquipmentInfo")
                    val secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus = dbEquipmentInfo.secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus
                    val isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase = dbEquipmentInfo.isDeviceUpdateMode
                     if (secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus == CHECKED_YES && isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase){
                        val updateDeviceListRequestBody =  ApiUpdateDeviceList(
                                deviceEquipmentId = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceEquipmentId,
                                secondaryDeviceId = dbEquipmentInfo.secondaryDeviceId,
                                deviceInstanceId = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceInstanceId.toString(),
                                deviceSerialNumber = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceSerialNumber,
                                devicePartNumber = dbEquipmentInfo.devicePartNumber,
                                deviceManufacturerName = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceManufacturer,
                                deviceInstallationDate = DateUtil.dateToStringUTCSiteSurvey(dbEquipmentInfo.deviceInstallationDate),
                                deviceLocation = dbEquipmentInfo.locationInfo,
                                deviceTechnicianNotes = dbEquipmentInfo.deviceTechnicianNotes
                        )
                        Log.d(TAG, "updateDeviceListRequestBodyAPI $updateDeviceListRequestBody")
                        updateDeviceListRequestBody
                    } else Unit.apply {  } //<- the issue is here 
    
                }) as List<ApiUpdateDeviceList>,
                removedDeviceList = List(dbInfo.sSDbInfo.removedDeviceList.size) { i ->
                    val dbRemovedMediaItem = dbInfo.sSDbInfo.removedDeviceList[i]
                    Log.d(TAG, "RemovedListDB $dbRemovedMediaItem")
                   
    

                    if (dbRemovedMediaItem.removedDeviceEquipmentId == null && dbRemovedMediaItem.removedMediaName.isNullOrEmpty()){
                       val removeDevice =  apiDeviceListMapperUpdateSiteSurvey.removeDevice(dbRemovedMediaItem)
                        Log.d(TAG, "removeDevice $removeDevice")
                        removeDevice
                    }else{
                        val removeMediaForExistingDevice = apiDeviceListMapperUpdateSS.removeMediaForExistingDevice(dbRemovedMediaItem)
                        Log.d(TAG, "removeMediaForExistingDevice $removeMediaForExistingDevice")
                        removeMediaForExistingDevice
                    }
                }
            )
            Log.d(TAG, "MainUpdateRequestAPI $updateRequestApi")
            return updateRequestApi
        }
```

The goal is to have the else statement that is highlighted to return an emptyList "[]" to that updateDeviceList field. I have tried a few ways but never was able to return that exact empty list "[]". Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if you want (1) the whole list to be invalidated and become empty if any item in the iteration fails the `if` check, or if you just want (2) to filter out items that fail the if check. But here's how I would approach each of those tasks.

I am breaking out the conversion between `DbEquipmentInfo` and `ApiUpdateDeviceList` into a separate extension function (`fun DbEquipmentInfo.toApiUpdateDeviceList(): ApiUpdateDeviceList`). Not just to avoid code repetition, but also to keep the logic code easy to read, and make the project's code more maintainable in general.

1.

```
val isValid = dbInfo.equipmentList.all { dbEquipmentInfo -> 
        val secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus = dbEquipmentInfo.secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus
        val isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase = dbEquipmentInfo.isDeviceUpdateMode
        secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus == CHECKED_YES && isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase
    }
updateDeviceList = 
    if (isValid) dbInfo.equipmentList.map { it.toApiUpdateDeviceList() }
    else emptyList()
```

2. 

```
updateDeviceList = dbInfo.equipmentList.filter { dbEquipmentInfo -> 
        val secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus = dbEquipmentInfo.secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus
        val isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase = dbEquipmentInfo.isDeviceUpdateMode
        secondaryDeviceCheckedStatus == CHECKED_YES && isDuplicateDeviceInUpdatePhase
    }.map { it.toApiUpdateDeviceList() }
```

Comment: BIG THANKS MAN. I have been hacking at this legacy code for a bit now and this was the part that was tripping me up BIG TIME. I haven't used extension functions as much myself, so absolutely looking that up to add to the tool box.